# c++ - Data Types Evaluate Differently

Tags: c++, types

I'm still very new to c++ so this might be a stupid question. In the code below why is it that when i change the type of index to a signed char, `index > 25` evaluates to true. Isn't a signed char just a 1 byte integer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char lowercase [26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

int main() {
    short index;

    cout << "Enter a number 0 to 25: ";
    cin >> index;
    if (index > 25 || index < 0) {
        cout << "That number is out of range." << endl;
        return 0;   
    }
    cout << "The lowercase letter for this number is " << lowercase[index] << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `short` here when `int` will do?

Comment: You did not say what value you are typing in, or what value `index` is actually receiving. And you are not checking whether `cin >>` succeeds or fails.

Comment: I don't know why i've chosen to use a `short` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rephrase the problem just a bit:

```
char index;
cin >> index;
```

It may be easier to see the problem.  When you read input into a `char`, you get the character code for the first character entered by the user.  In a typical system, this is ASCII, and the code for digits is between 48 and 57.

So when you get input into `index` when it is a signed character, you'll get a value that is >= 48.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that a `signed char` was different than a `char` in that a `signed char` would just be a 1 byte integer.

Comment: @AlarmedDino `char` and `signed char` are both 1-byte integers. The difference is that `operator>>(istream&, char&)` has different behaviour to `operator>>(istream&, short&)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a when the user enters a value between 0 to 25, the value that is evaluated pertain to the ascii table 0 == 48 (ascii). The datatype char will only that in the first value that is entered, single digit/letter e.g. char foo = "1"